# Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type NSMutableArrayの警告が出ます。

Tags: objective-c, iphone

画面遷移の際の

```
classViewController.records = [[LessonManager sharedManager].lessons[self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems]records];
```

で

```
Expected method to read dictionary element not found on object of type NSMutableArray
```

と警告が発生します 印はLessonManagerのところについています。

どのように直せばいいのでしょうか。

Comment: `LessonManager`の`lessons`プロパティが`NSDictionary`じゃないので添え字によるアクセスはできないというメッセージです。`lessons`プロパティの定義はどうなっていますか？

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。lessonsはこのような感じになっています。@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *lessons;
テーブルビューで
'[[LessonManager sharedManager].lessons[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow.row] records];'
このようになっているのですが、この指定をコレクションビューでもやりたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UICollectionView`の`- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedItems;`は`NSArray`を返します（複数セルの選択に対応している）。`NSArray`なのでそのままでは`lessons`プロパティの添え字として利用できません。

コレクションビューで複数選択を禁止しているなら中身は空か１つだけ入ってるかのどちらかなので、`firstObject`メソッドなどで配列から取り出して、空でなければ添え字として利用する、といった処理になると思います。

```
NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems.firstObject;
if (selectedIndexPath) {
    classViewController.records = [[LessonManager sharedManager].lessons[selectedIndexPath.item] records];
}
```